# junit throwing 'No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2000' with h2 gis

Tags: spring-boot, junit, gis, h2

I have an entity defined as:

```
public class GeometryEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "feature_type")
    private String featureType;

    @Column(name = "geom")
    private Geometry geometry;
}
```

And corresponding JpaRepository defined as:

```
public interface GeometryRepository extends JpaRepository<GeometryEntity, UUID> {
}
```

I am trying to write a integration test for this using h2(with gis):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource({"classpath:application-test.properties"})
public class GeometryRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    GeometryRepository geometryRepository;

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        assertNotNull(this.geometryRepository);
    }
}
```

In application-test.properties, I have configured:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.h2geodb.GeoDBDialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

But when I run the test, I get error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2000
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
```

Comment: Right, its failing only in test. Application works fine.

Comment: Apart from db related stuff, I have spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect in it. Are other details needed?